# If iOS has low battery mode does macOS have that too?

Tags: macos

In iOS, there is an option to enable low power mode. This mode reduces network traffic and other battery draining activities. Is it possible to have this option on macOS?

Here is my battery preferences screen:

[image]

Aside: Does Power nap conserve energy or use energy to enable network calls when sleeping?

OSX Catalina Wine Mixer 10.15.7

Comment: My interpretation of Power Nap is that is uses more energy during sleep if enabled.

Comment: @PierU same thank you

Answer (score 2):

First result after googling "macOS low battery mode":

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh35848/mac

> On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Battery , click Battery or Power Adapter, then do any of the following:
>
> - To reduce energy usage to increase battery life, select “Low power mode”.
> - To set the computer or display to sleep at different times when you’re using the battery or connected to power, drag the “Turn display off after” slider.
> - To save energy, select “Put hard disks to sleep when possible”.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see the Low Power mode option but I do see the other options. I've added a screen shot into the post.

Comment: May not be available for your model/macos version. The mode is not described for Catalina on the link I gave, it seems that Monterey is required.

Comment: I think you're right. I still have to upgrade. IIRC The download is 15GB then requires 30GB additional to install. Didn't have the space at the time :|